# How to save cached network image in external storage?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using [cached_network_image](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image) plugin to cache images in flutter. It is working fine. Now I want to save image at path provided by `getExternalStorageDirectory()` from [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) plugin without again downloading image from internet. How do I do this?

Comment: Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: I could be wrong, but path_provider alone is only capable of setting the path. You'll still have to hook up a database to actually store the information. Like hive, sembast, sqflite or moor... any one of them can do it (probably missed one)..